# Kodak i1120 network Scanning

Tags: rdp, twain, isis

i am having a problem with this Scanner (Kodak i1120). I have a thinclient with an active rdp session. The thinclient can Scan without any problem but the rdp session can not. I have tried multiple Software and multiple protocols (TWAIN and ISIS) but can not make it work. Have anyone does something similar in the past?

I would appreciate all the help i can get....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using RDP, look into Microsoft RemoteFX USB Redirection (you need an RDP 7.1 client for it to work).

This will allow your RDP session to access the USB device connected to your thin client.  It does require installing the scanner drivers on the server for it to work properly.

You can also look into other networking options, like Silex...